# tbody don't appear when I scrape data python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, https, datatable

I try to extract data in table but it isn't successful --"

I see that on the website:
[(https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00696X0126/F2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fY1V.png)

here is my code:

```py
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = PhantomJSpath)
url = 'https://ades.eaufrance.fr/Fiche/PtEau?Code=00871X0002'
browser.get(url)
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
soup = bs(browser.page_source, features='lxml')
tables = soup.find_all('table')
for elem in tables:
    print(elem)
```

I get table but the element "tbody" disappears:
[My scraping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EezDb.png)

What am I not doing right?
If someone can show me the path thanks.

Comment: There are **8** _tables_ with **5** of them having `<tbody>`. What is your usecase? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to extract data of two first tables. But i have only header of every tables

Answer (score -1):

Element `tbody` is absent in your results since you are scraping `page_source`, but not actual rendered HTML-tree. Note that `tbody` element added by your Browser while rendering the page.
IMHO it's not a problem at all, so you don't need to worry about this "issue"

P.S. I would recommend to use built-in Selenium methods/properties for getting data from page instead of using 3-party BeautifulSoup library